# I am trying to make a window/frame containing a picture that allows you to click through it

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, wxpython, wxwidgets, pywin32

Just to clarify my goal. I am trying to get a resizable (via mouse click and drag) window that is see through, and allows you to change the transparency of it by up and down arrows.

I want it to ask for an image, and then rescale it as you drag the window.

The key feature which I have working is to allow users to click through it.

The issue that I am running into is I can't place an image inside the frame, nor move or resize it.

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import win32con
import win32gui
import sys
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import wx


def scale_bitmap(bitmap, width, height):
    image = wx.ImageFromBitmap(bitmap)  #was wx.imageFromBitmap(bitmap)
    image = image.Scale(width, height, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
    result = wx.BitmapFromImage(image)
    return result

imageName = input("Enter name of image file")
im1 = Image.open("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\Tracing Images" + "\\" + imageName )

#r, g, b,  = im1.split()
#im1 = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b))
im1.save("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\Tracing Images\\converted\\"  +str("1") + ".bmp")
Imgbmp = Image.open("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\Tracing Images\\converted\\" +str("1") + ".bmp")
#convert image into bitmap?


app = wx.App()
trans = 50
# create a window/frame, no parent, -1 is default ID
# change the size of the frame to fit the backgound images
frame1 = wx.Frame(None, -1, "KExA", style=wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
# create the class instance
frame1.Show()  #was frame1.ShowFullScreen(True)

image_file = win32gui.SystemParametersInfo(win32con.SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, 0)
bmp1 = image_file
bmp1 = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap() #trying to remove this see if it fixes anything
bmp1 = scale_bitmap(bmp1, GetSystemMetrics(1) * 1.5, GetSystemMetrics(1))
bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(frame1, -1, bmp1, (-100, 0))
hwnd = frame1.GetHandle()

extendedStyleSettings = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE)
win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE,
                       extendedStyleSettings | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED | win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT)
win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 255, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)

frame1.SetTransparent(trans)


def onKeyDown(e):
    global trans
    key = e.GetKeyCode()
    if key == wx.WXK_UP:
        print()
        trans
        trans += 10
        if trans > 255:
            trans = 255
    elif key == wx.WXK_DOWN:
        print()
        trans
        trans -= 10
        if trans < 0:
            trans = 0
    try:
        win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, trans, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)
    except:
        pass


frame1.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown)

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Your program appears to be using the wxPython GUI, but you are trying to use win32gui to paste the image into the frame.  Do you know if that can possibly work?  wxPython is cross-platform and win32gui isn't, so I don't see how they could be compatible.  wxPython has lots of tools for manipulating images; is there some reason that you switch to win32gui for this purpose?

Comment: So win32gui I used because I was under the impression that is what I needed to allow the ''click through window'' feature so that I can click through it to something behind. But I see that perhaps I need to change my approach

Answer (score 0):

If you use `wx.Image` to manage your image, you can access the `Scale` function, which will allow you to tie the size of the image to size of the window, or anything else for that matter.

For example:

```
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args)
        self.Img = wx.Image("wxPython.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        Imgsize = self.Img.GetWidth(), self.Img.GetHeight()
        self.SetSize(Imgsize)
        self.Image = wx.StaticBitmap(self, bitmap=wx.Bitmap(self.Img))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.onResize)
        self.Show()

    def onResize(self, event):
        frame_h, frame_w = self.GetSize()
        img = self.Img.Scale(frame_h, frame_w)
        self.Image = wx.StaticBitmap(self, bitmap=wx.Bitmap(img))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    myframe = TestFrame(None, -1, "Resize Me")
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]